# Set Custom Typeface(font) for AlertDialog's MultiSelectItems

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-font

I have been able to apply the custom font to the title of the Alert dialog as below:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 TextView Mytitle = new TextView(this);
 Mytitle.setText("My Custom title"); 
 Mytitle.setTextSize(20);
 Mytitle.setPadding(5, 15, 5, 5);
 Mytitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 Mytitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "myfont.ttf"));
 builder.setCustomTitle(Mytitle);
```

The alert Dialog displays a list of Multiselect Items populated by the line below.

```
 builder.setMultiChoiceItems(MyItems, MycheckedItems, MyDialogListener);

 //where MyItems is CharSequence[] Array, MycheckedItems => boolean[] array,
 //MyDialogListener => DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
```

i want to apply a font to these multiselect items also. How can i do this? is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AlertDialog.Builder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/AlertDialog.java#AlertDialog.Builder) uses [AlertController.AlertParams](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#AlertController.AlertParams) to construct a dialog. I examined that AlertDialog.Builder#create() calls AlertController.AlertParams#apply() which creates ListView and assign adapter, if items are set ([AlertParams#createListView()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#AlertController.AlertParams.createListView%28com.android.internal.app.AlertController%29)).

I created custom adapter based on createListView sources and modified android cell layout:

```
public static class TypefaceDialog extends DialogFragment {
        private static final CharSequence[] items = {
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"
        };
        private static final boolean[] checked = {
            true, false, false, true, true, false, false
        };

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Typeface fontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Arial Bold.ttf");
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                    getActivity(), 
                    android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, 
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    items) {

                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                    textView.setChecked(checked[position]);
                    textView.setTypeface(fontTypeface);
                    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            CheckedTextView view = (CheckedTextView)v;
                            view.setChecked(!view.isChecked());
                            checked[position] = view.isChecked();
                        }
                    });

                    return view;
                }
            };

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setAdapter(adapter, null)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .create();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this out after long long time. and it works like a charm.

Comment: is it possible to set the font for the positive, Neutral and Negative buttons also?

Comment: Can you put example usage of this class?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom adapter for the multiple select with a custom item layout.

Set the Typeface as **static** within your activity or application

```
public static Typeface mFont;
public void OnCreate(){
mFont =Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
}
```

In your custom adapter, set the typeface of the textview from your convertView using the static typeface.

Comment: "creating a custom adapter for the multiple select with a custom item layout." Could you give me a bit more input on this?

Comment: Here is a helpful blog  http://adanware.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **AlertDialog.Builder** use **Dialog** like as follow .

Inside the **R.layout.vv** customize as like you want.

```
Dialog dailog=new Dialog(this);
dailog.setContentView(R.layout.vv);
dailog.show();
```